# Android Biometric Authentication return "unique id" and encrypt with it

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

i am having problem.
I have searched google for biometric authentication but all example apis just returns me "authentication success" with boolean value.

Example:
https://proandroiddev.com/5-steps-to-implement-biometric-authentication-in-android-dbeb825aeee8

I want to encrypt SQL with user's biometric id.
The biometric id will be the key.
It can be 256bit or 64bit key.

Is there any library for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the `authenticate(crypto)` methods of either the `android.hardware.BiometricPrompt (framework)` or `androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt libraries (recommended)` APIs?

Here is some reference. You basically `initialize` a key in `KeyStore`, wrap it into the appropriate `CryptoObject` (in your case, probably Cipher for encrypt/decrypt). When you `authenticate(crypto)`, upon user authentication the key becomes unlocked and you can operate with it.

Here's the [demo app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/samples/BiometricDemos/src/main/java/com/example/android/biometric/BiometricPromptDemoBiometricBoundKeyActivity.java) for the `androidx.biometric` library